# What if Twitter or Facebook accounts are not configured on iOS 6?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, ios6, social-framework

Does anybody know a smart way to bring the user to enter their Facebook or Twitter account login information, if they aren't already logged in? For example, a user tries to log in my application with Facebook without configuring the Facebook account in the iOS settings. Can I ask him to do it with an alert, for example, but how can I bring him to the exact section of settings for that?

Comment: You can setup your account in settings for twitter using this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335795/login-user-with-twitter-in-ios-what-to-use/13951630#13951630

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@rckoenes is correct. Under normal circumstances there is no way to manually send the user to preferences. There was a method of doing this introduced in iOS 5, but Apple quickly depreciated it in iOS 5.0.1 or 5.1 I don't remember exactly which one.

Now, on to the current situation. If you are using an `SLComposeViewController` in the `Social Framework`, you don't even have to worry about adding this functionality yourself. It is done automatically by iOS. Below is a screenshot from my 6.0 simulator attempting to post to Facebook without any accounts signed in. This is also true for Twitter and Sina Weibo.

[image]

Comment: What a shame... I hope Apple fixes it the sooner the better. I don't see the point on using the dialog you are showing, with the compose, and not with the "login" and the other functions...

Comment: This Alert view only appears on simulator, on devices it will not appear. It seems that this is a bug!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, there is no way to get the user to the settings app lett a lone the correct section.