# Login user with twitter in iOS... what to use?

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, ios6, restkit

I know similar questions have been asked before (I've read most of them), but I haven't found a good answer yet.

I need to login/signup users with twitter from iOS. I have this website where I am already doing that (www.Meer.li) and now I need to do it in the app as well.

I know I can get access to the twitter username on the iOS-device and see if it is in the database of my app, but how do I handle things when the user isn't signed up to www.Meer.li yet?

Sorry if it is a trivial question, but I'm a bit confused wether I should use the iOS Social framework or use some OAuth library (Restkit, etc).

Hope someone can guide me in the direction of an answer or maybe even an example!

**To be clarified:**

Thanks a lot for the guidance. Seems reasonable. Just to be sure, this is how I understand the steps to be:

1: User clicks on login with twitter button

2: We get users twitter accounts and ask him which one he wants to use

3: We send off a request to twitter with the key and secret for your own app and the users twitter info

4: If good response is received back, send the received info to the method on your webapp that creates users and make a request from there to twitter for the remaining user info

5: Let user have fun

Is that about right? Why hasn't anyone documented this flow very well before? Sounds like a thing that should be very easy to do.

Comment: Please see the new methods in iOS 5+ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244861/twitter-integration-issue-with-acaccountstore-ios-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** iOS 5+ takes care of all of the OAuth and heavy lifting for you so only use this answer if you're supporting older OS versions.

There is a good WWDC 2012 presentation about how to do this now that the Twitter.framework is deprecated.  Login to see this link: http://adcdownload.apple.com/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_306__integrating_with_facebook_twitter_and_sina_weibo.pdf

---

i just had to do this myself.

by far the best answer i found was [Sean Cook's TWReverseAuthExample](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample) .  (i forked his github project, then boiled it down to the essentials i needed as a submodule for my ARC-based apps in [TWReverseAuthSubModule](https://github.com/johnkdoe/TWReverseAuthSubmodule), stripping out the example project, et al, since i knew i could get back to it at the original github source.)

basically, if you follow the example, it follows through on the steps [outlined on the Twitter API web pages](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth).

in the end, what you need to do is create code that looks pretty much like sean's example.

there were other resources on the net which i had originally started using which allowed me to "login using twitter" in ways that would do the authorization in a nested UIWebView or even going out to safari and then coming back into the app via dedicated app URL scheme.  and these might be helpful if you need to do pre-iOS 5.x stuff.

but the example above takes the best advantage of native iOS twitter support, and works also with iOS 6 .

Comment: That's an awesome stripped down library for doing reverse oAuth. I finally managed to get it to work and it's nice and smooth. Would be great if you could give an example on Github on how to integrate it into a project though.

Comment: For iOS 7, you have to add Twitter, Social, Accounts framework and need to go through these links now https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request .. Sign in in twitter and add your app in https://apps.twitter.com/

Comment: could you please share sample code for "Sign in with twitter". I am not able to get this.

Answer (score 1):

Prompt login alert with Twitter framework in iOS5:
[Prompt login alert with Twitter framework in iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667921/prompt-login-alert-with-twitter-framework-in-ios5)

Prompt login alert with Twitter framework in iOS6:
[Twitter Framework for ios6 how to login through settings from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946062/twitter-framework-for-ios6-how-to-login-through-settings-from-app)

Comment: Any time there is already an existing answer on StackOverflow, it should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reverse auth method provided by twitter, you need your server support this.

Here is the link:https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting for pre iOS 5.x, then an OAuth login with UIWebView is necessary.
And you can skip my answer from here...

But if targeting iOS 5.0+, I'd recommend the iOS Twitter Framework. As Twitter's official doc says [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios#Single_Sign-On). Apple integrates Twitter for a reason, and I bet more people are using iOS 5.x or 6.x.
In this case, it's just a simple step-by-step procedure, with all the APIs available, and no key or secret is needed.

1. Obtain the account instance for the user's Twitter account
2. Request permission from the user to access the available Twitter accounts
3. Grab the available accounts
4. Make an authenticated request

The problem then might be: if the user is not logged in on the device, you may need to remind him to go to Settings and do the loggin stuff, or use a "tricky" way to show log-in:

```
- (void)showTwitterSettings{
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

// Create the completion handler block.
[tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
 {
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }];

// Present the tweet composition view controller modally.
[self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
//tweetViewController.view.hidden = YES;
for (UIView *view in tweetViewController.view.subviews){
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

}