# iOS - Twitter login with username and password

Tags: ios, twitter, ios7

I'm new to iOS development so I'm not clear about how to go about this: with the username and password provided by the user, check if the credentials is a valid twitter account. Log the user in and retrieve the users followers, account information, timeline and tweets.

I know I haven't tried anything, but it's just because I have no clue where to start. I did some searching up on it and found something about OAuth. but most of the stuff out there is for iOS 5.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa/

Comment: @jycr753 I'm looking on how to log the user into twitter given the username and password by the user...

Comment: the best sample i can find is this one:: https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample

Comment: also have a look here :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335795/login-user-with-twitter-in-ios-what-to-use

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Social.framework` (iOS6 and above). It manages authentication to several social networking sites, including twitter. Once the user has created an account and granted your app access to it, you can use `SLRequest` to perform authenticated twitter (or whatever) http requests without having to directly use Oauth.

First you get the `ACAccount`.

```
#import <Social/Social.h>   // SLRequest

- (void)getTwitter {
    ACAccountType *accountType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (granted) {
                // access granted, get account info
                NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                ACAccount *account = [accounts lastObject];

                // yay, now you can use account for authenticated twitter requests
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Access not granted: %@\n", error);
            }
        }
     ];
}
```

Then you can start making authenticated requests, e.g. get account info

```
- (void)getTwitterAccount:(ACAccount *)account {
    NSString *get = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:get];
    NSDictionary *parms = @{ @"include_entities" : @"false", @"skip_status" : @"true" };

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:url parameters:parms ];
    request.account = account;

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error){
        if(!error) {
            NSLog(@"response: %@\n", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"performRequestWithHandler error %@\n",  error);
        }
    }];
}
```

See the [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) for timeline, tweets, etc.