# iOS: How to create a Twitter log in button

Tags: ios, twitter, authentication

I have been looking everywhere for this. I need a button that a user can press that will log them in using Twitter and be sent to the next view controller. Please be as detailed as you possibly can be for I do not know where to start.

What I am looking for is something like the Facebook Login View. Where you use a UIView and custom class it as FBLoginView and it turns into the button and from there you can use the delegated methods to log the user in.

It would be great if it was like that.

Comment: try this ::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335795/login-user-with-twitter-in-ios-what-to-use

Comment: Already saw that. That link and it's "answers" contain no code and no comprehensive solution. Only another link to a broken solution. Please help. Someone.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty decent tutorial here with code, http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Twitter_Integration_Tutorial_using_SLRequest