# Twitter framework account configuration in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i am using the latest

> twitter framework of ios to tweet to my account
>
> .All is working fine if the user had already configured the twiiter
>   account

.

> If he had not configured the account i am presenting an alert that to
>   configure the account.thats all.
>
> is it the right approach
>
> or i need to put one settings button in the alert if so how can i go
>   to settings of the twitter account when i click on that.

..Can any body clear the air here?

Comment: `twitter framework of ios` which framework you are using social or twitter.framework?

Comment: @Anil twitter framework...

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12847449/1328096 but it is true that this Alert view only appears on simulator, on devices it will not appear. It seems that this is a bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using twitter framework even in social framework in iOS6 also, if the user is not configured the twitter account  the system will generate an alert. You dont want worry about that, they will provide an option to goto to the settings also. The alert looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good framework addressing that concern : [REActivityViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REActivityViewController)

When the user click to share, twitter (and other optional sharing services) button appear even if the user did not configure it. It's only when he clicks it that the pop-up tells him that he has to configure it and offers a "settings" button to send him at the correct location.